# Comparing str date (from database) with QDateTimeEdit value

Tags: python, datetime, qt5

I like to compare a string parsed from a database with a DateTime value of a QDateTimeEdit (created by qt designer).
What is the best solution for it?

My QDateTimeEdit is named qDateTimeFrom.
My str object is named strFrom.

```
dateFrom = self.qDateTimeFrom.dateTime()
strFrom = '2018-01-05-22.49.15.630000'
 # convert (str to QDateTime object?)
qstrFrom = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(strFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss")
 # compare
if(dateFrom > qstrFrom ):
  print('dateFrom is bigger than strFrom')
elif(dateFrom == qStrFrom):
  print('dateFrom is exactly strFrom')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
dateFrom = self.qDateTimeFrom.dateTime()
strFrom = '2018-01-05-22.49.15.630000'

 # convert (QDateTimeEdit to string; then string to DateTime)
dateFrom = dateFrom.toString(self.dateFrom.displayFormat())
dateFromDT = datetime.strptime(str(dateFrom),'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

 # convert (String to DateTime)
strFromDT = datetime.strptime(str(strFrom),'%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f')

 # compare
if(dateFromDT > strFromDT ):
  print('dateFromDT is bigger than strFromDT')
print('Difference: ' + str(dateFromDT - strFromDT))
```